# Namespacing within `app` directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, autoload

In our `app` directory, we want some of the sub-directories to contain namespaced classes, and some that contain top-level classes. For example:

- `app/models/user.rb` defines `::User`
- `app/operations/foo.rb` defines `::Operations::Foo`
- `app/operations/user/foo.rb` defines `::Operations::User::Foo`

Our `application.rb` contains the following configuration:

```
config.paths = Rails::Paths::Root.new(Rails.root)
config.paths.add 'app/models', eager_load: true
config.paths.add 'app', eager_load: true
```

This works fine in most cases, but sometimes in development mode and with Rails' autoreloading turned on, this leads to the wrong classes being loaded. For instance `::User` is mistaken for `Operations::User` and vice-versa.

Is there a way to configure this behavior so that it works without any errors?

If not, the only workaround I can think of is to create a second directory for "namespaced" classes, along the lines of `app` and `app_namespaced`. Or else `app/namespaced`, since app-level code should reside within `app`. But these seem like ugly workarounds to me.

Edit: A little example as asked for by @dgilperez:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User
end

# app/models/group.rb
class Group
  def some_method
    # Since we're in a top-level namespace, User should always
    # resolve to ::User. But, depending on some seemingly random
    # factors, it sometimes resolves to Operations::User.
    User.new
  end
end

# app/operations.rb
module Operations
end

# app/operations/user/create.rb
module Operations::User
  class Create
    def some_method
      # Here, as expected, I need to prefix with "::" as
      # 'User' would refer to the module we're currently in.
      # That's fine and works.
      ::User.new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You could use fully qualified constants or `require_dependency` as described in [When Constants aren't Missed](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#when-constants-aren-t-missed)

Comment: Can you paste the definition of the classes? And the code that originates the confusion (call and location)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @dgilperez, I've just added a little example.

Comment: Can you try split `Operations::User` into `module Operations; module User; end; end`. Not really sure that's your case, but I've seen Rails autoloading perform in unexpected ways with definitions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a downside of rails' autoloading. By default, it loads everything from `/app`, but first level of directory structure is not part of the names. It's so that `app/models/user.rb` can define `User`, not require it to be `Models::User`.

You don't need to mess with the load paths. Several approaches/workarounds available here.

1. In my current project we just double the namespacing directory. Meaning that if we want to define `ServiceObjects::User::Import`, we put it into `app/service_objects/service_objects/user/import.rb`
2. I personally prefer a variation of that approach, which is to put all "non-standard" stuff into `app/lib` (can be `app/custom` or anything you want). This way, there's no weird duplication of directory names and all custom code is nicely contained.